# Apache Cordova: remove tap-hold link menu

Tags: iphone, apache, cordova

I am currently developing an iPhone app using Apache Cordova (phonegap) and xcode to build it. It is running along nicely, but I have bumped in to a problem. As the Apache Cordova solution uses Webview, when you tap-hold links it open a dialogue from the bottom asking if you want to open the link, or copy the url. Is there a way to remove this? Alternatively, is there a way to create links through another method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed the problem with some CSS.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

Comment: Where you place this? Inside of body: `body{ -webkit-touch-callout:none; }` or where? Thanks!

Comment: I think it'd be for all elements: `* { -webkit-touch-callout: none; }`